# Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this error, but I don't really know why:

> Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element

HTML:

```
<div class="reveal"></div>
```

JavaScript / jQuery:

```
var reveal = $('.reveal');
reveal.css('margin', '10px');
var resulte = window.getComputedStyle(reveal, 'margin');
```

Comment: How about `window.getComputedStyle(reveal[0], 'margin');`?

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen arf same error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getComputedStyle()` is a JavaScript function that expects a JavaScript object, not a jQuery object. Pass it `reveal[0]` and it will work.

The second argument of the `getComputedStyle()` function is optional and it is for the pseudo element, not the CSS property. You can use `getComputedStyle()` to get all the properties and then use `getPropertyValue('margin')` to get the  specific property that you want.

The problem is when you assign a value to the `margin` property in jQuery like this `reveal.css('margin', '10px')`, then it gets applies to each of the margins (top, right, bottom, and left) and the `margin` property will return nothing (in some browsers). You'll have to get each margin separately.

```js
var reveal = $('.reveal');
reveal.css('margin', '10px');
var resulte = window.getComputedStyle(reveal[0], null).getPropertyValue('margin-top');

console.log(resulte);
```

```css
.reveal {
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reveal"></div>
```

Comment: Note that `getPropertyValue('margin')` only works in some browsers like I said. Use specific margins `getPropertyValue('margin-top')` if you want it to work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're passing a `jQuery` object where an `Element`[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) is expected.

You're mixing up jQuery and (vanilla/plain) JavaScript, which are NOT the same. JavaScript  is a language and jQuery is a library that allows you to deal with (primarily) the DOM.

A jQuery object not always interchangeable with JavaScript so you need to extract the actual matched elements.

A jQuery object (from the top of my head) is basically an advanced iterable which contains all of it's matched elements in inside. If you only expect one match it should be in `reveal[0]`.

`reveal[0]` should in that case be an `Element` or `HTMLElement` which you can then pass to the `window.getComputedStyle`[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) function.